# Creating a loop in Python and taking the average reading

Tags: python, loops, average, distance, sensors

First off, I'm no way a programmer, I can hack together code, but am getting stumped on this one. I have a sonar distance sensor and I want to take 10 readings to find the average of those readings. I've found that the first reading is usually way off, so figured 10 would be a good number. Found some tutorials on basic loops, but can't figure out how to apply it to my situation. Here's the piece of code I want to loop and the current output. Any suggestions?

```
GPIO.output(PIN_TRIGGER, GPIO.HIGH)

  time.sleep(0.00001)

  GPIO.output(PIN_TRIGGER, GPIO.LOW)

  while GPIO.input(PIN_ECHO)==0:
        pulse_start_time = time.time()
  while GPIO.input(PIN_ECHO)==1:
        pulse_end_time = time.time()

  pulse_duration = pulse_end_time - pulse_start_time
  distance = round(pulse_duration * 17150, 2)
  print "Distance:",distance,"cm"
```

Comment: I'm assuming the code you shared works for you and gets you a single reading in `distance`, correct? And you want to take 10 readings like that one after the other and compute the average of those 10 readings? So, for each of 10 readings, you want to add those readings together and divide the sum by 10?

Comment: Yep. Exactly right. Code currently works, and give me one reading.

Comment: If you watched some tutorials on loops and paid attention, surely you found some clues on how to attempt coding "for each of 10 readings, you want to add those readings together and divide the sum by 10"? Please share what you tried and explain what it is you don't understand if it doesn't work.

Comment: My coding ability is very minimal. I did watch some tutorials and got the jist of what they were doing, but they were too general. Many only used one While. I don't understand how to create a loop using my current While statements. Everything I've tried just gives me errors.

Comment: I can figure out how to manually do multiple readings and take the average of those numbers, but figured I should try and do it the correct way with less code. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to discard the first reading then average the next 10.  The easiest way to average 10 readings is a loop like so:

```
accumulator = 0
for _ in range(10):
    reading = take_reading()
    accumulator += reading
average = accumulator / 10
```

Explanantion:

`accumulator = 0`  this initializes a variable to store the sum of your readings.

`for _ in range(10):`  We want to go through our loop 10 times.  We do not need to do anything with our loop counter, so we can use underscore `_` instead of defining a variable to catch that.

`reading = take_reading()`  get the data we are after.

`accumulator += reading`  add our current data to our accumulator.

`average = accumulator / 10`  this line not being indented ends the `for` loop.
 Take the average of our 10 readings.

Ideally, you would want to put the reading taking process into a function that `return`s the reading.  Then you can set up your loop to get multiple readings just like my example.

Comment: okay okay. Thats helping. doing some looking into that, and I assume those would be set by DEF?

Comment: yeah,  `def  take_reading():`  then indent your lines of code to get a reading under that.  Finish up by `return`ing the value you read.

Comment: Awesome! Got it! Had to do some trial and error, but now understand how it needed to work. Got it going! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Good to hear that you figured it out.  and thanks for the check.